# Function and binary operation

Tags: lisp

I want to create a function : OP from `i=n` to `p = f(i)`
OP is a binary operator

Here is my function

```
(defun sigmaOP (f o n p)
(loop for i from n to p do
(let (val (o (val (funcall f i))))
)
val
)
```

f is a function
o is the operator
n is the begining and p the end

And to call I use

```
(sigmaOP (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) '+ 1 3)
```

But it doesn't work
The o argument isn't consider as operator.
This function work if I remove `o` and instead there is `+ or *,`...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An operator is a function to call, too, so you need to precede `o` with `funcall`, or use it as a parameter in a call e.g. to reduce. Are you thinking of something like this?

```
(defun sigmaOP (f o n p)
  (reduce o
    (loop for i from n to p
          collect (funcall f i))))
```

Call:

```
(sigmaOP (lambda (x) (* 2 x)) #'+ 1 3)
```

Comment: I try your code but it doesn't work.
Maybe my function call is bad.
How you call this function to pass the operator as argument simply + or '+ ?

Comment: @guillaume: see my edits. Since `o` is a local variable, we don't need to function-quote it.

Comment: Argh. Always had a problem with Lisp-2... I'm more of a Scheme guy. Thanks for the edit!